# Apps corner disappeared from start screen, How can I bring it back?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps-corner

I have pinned the "Apps corner" app on the start screen for fast access. All of a sudden it disappeared from the start screen. I went back to check the app from the settings. I found that the pin button is greyed out which indicates the app should be pinned on the start screen. The only possible way to access the app now is from the settings which I find it very annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the settings app is not able to detect the pin status of the apps corner application.. Windows 10 mobile is still not as stable as it should be and there is nothing much we can do for a OS setting app except trying these..
(If you haven't already) :

1. **Restarting the device**. A simple restart fixes multiple issues like background task memory usage or tile not updating etc .
2. If restarting does not work try **soft reset**
3. The last resort for solving almost any problem is a **hard reset** (which restores factory settings and deletes personal settings,apps etc. ) Though if you have backup enabled your settings can be restored.

[More info on Soft and Hard Reset](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d)

Comment: I have tried the first two solutions. The only one left is a hard reset which I am not willing to do and there is no compelling reason for me right now to do it. Thanks for your help.